# What is wrong with my Riemann Calculation?

Tags: python, numpy, sum

So I need to calculate a left, mid and right Riemann sum but my while loop that does the calculations is off. I don't know where it is wrong, I am checking with Symbolab and I'm only off by a little.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot(f, a = 0, b = 1, m = str('center'), n = 10):

    par = (b - a)/1000
    x = np.arange(a, b, par)
    plt.plot(x, f(x), 'black')
    w = (b - a)/n
    i = 1
    v = 0
```

### This is jut plotting the graph, does not need to be grouped

```
if b < a:
    raise ValueError('Value b must be greater than a', b)
```

### Check if b is greater than a

```
if m not in ("center", "left","right"):
    raise ValueError('Value m must be one of the following: center, left, or right', m)
```

### Check if  m is valid

```
if n < 0:
    raise ValueError('N must be a positive integer', n)
```

### Check if n is positive and an integer

```
if m == 'center':
    d = w /2
    x2 = np.arange(a + d , b + d , w)
    plt.bar(x2,f(x2), align = 'center', color = 'blue',\
            edgecolor = 'black', width = w, alpha = 0.5)
    plt.show()

    while( i<=(n)):
        v += f(a+w*i) * w
        i = i+1

    print("The estimation using", m ,"is", v)
```

### V will find the estimation of integral using the method chosen

### Does Mid Point

```
if m == 'left':
    x2 = np.arange(a , b , w)
    plt.bar(x2,f(x2), align = 'edge', color = 'red',\
            edgecolor = 'black', width = w, alpha = 0.5)
    plt.show()
    while( i<=(n)):
        v += f(a+w*i) * w
        i = i+1
    print("The estimation using", m ,"is", v)
```

### V will find the estimation of integral using the method chosen

### Does Left Point

```
if m == 'right':
    x2 = np.arange(a + w, b + w , w)
    plt.bar(x2,f(x2), align = 'edge', color = 'orange',\
            edgecolor = 'black', width = -w, alpha = 0.5)
    plt.show()
    while( i<=(n)):
        v += f(a+w*i) * w
        i = i+1
    print("The estimation using", m ,"is", v)
```

### V will find the estimation of integral using the method chosen

### Does Right

I am not consistently getting the answers that I am checking with symbolab.

Comment: What are your inputs? What answer are you getting with your code and Symbolab? Is the difference within what would be expected from the fact that a Riemman sum for finite epsilon will have some error?

Comment: Can you get rid of all the plotting, and combine everything into a function (or three separate functions) with a return value (each)?